# Driving DUT using PyUVM

Tags: python, cocotb

I am trying to drive the DUT signals using PyUVM + COCOTB.
But DUT signals are not getting driven from pyuvm.

I am trying to drive DUT signals from PyUVM test .
Test is passing but signals are not being driven with the expected values .

Makeppfile

```
TOPLEVEL = ptb_dut
MODULE = base_class
TOPLEVEL_LANG = verilog
```

Design file

```
module ptb_dut(
    input clk_in,
    input [1:0] d,
     ....
     ....
);
```

Python test file

```
class base_class(uvm_test):
    async def run_phase(self):
        self.raise_objection()
        self.bfm = cocotb.top
        self.bfm.d.value = 2   ## This is not happening
```

Can you please help why "d" port is not updating ?

Comment: What makes you say the signal is not being updated?

Comment: Hi! Maybe this sounds a little weird, but are you sure that the run_phase() is being executed? With the context that you gave I don't see any reasons why it wouldn't work. The other thing that I'm thinking is: how the test is continuing? Maybe you're driving the d signal with another value at the same simulation time.